# jQuery not loading IE9 - standards?

Tags: jquery, html, xhtml, internet-explorer-9, doctype

Have a website that has been working fine, but just recently in IE9 it has stopped working.
the jQuery does not load. It has been fine up until now.

But anything that requires jQuery doesn't load, e.g. drop down menu, easy slider, colorbox.

When I look at developer tools it displays this in the Console:

```
HTML1113: Document mode restart from IE9 Standards to Quirks 
local.domain.com

HTML1113: Document mode restart from Quirks to IE9 Standards 
local.domain.com

HTML1201: chinacraftireland.com is a website you've added to Compatibility View. 
local.domain.com

HTML1113: Document mode restart from IE9 Standards to Quirks 
local.domain.com

HTML1113: Document mode restart from Quirks to IE9 Standards 
local.domain.com
```

I have changed the DocType but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

What would have caused this? It was working fine, has there been an update to IE9?

Comment: http://chinacraft.madebymint.biz/

Comment: `HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`  that's what showed up when trying to see your jQuery file.. check it's location

Comment: Or it might be that you have a console.log() line somewhere in your code.  IE will throw an error, and any script simply will not run.  Just a thought. . .

Comment: I'm sure the file isn't in your `js` folder.. check the name.. spelling make sure it's correct.. all your other .js files open fine except for jQuery.  Did you download 1.7.1 and put it inside the `js` folder?  I can hit your 1.6.2 jQuery file fine but your 1.7.1 seems like it doesn't exist there

Comment: Sorry, I had been making changes offline to try and rectify the problem, but forgot to upload when I posted the link

Comment: Take a look now. It is what the original code is when I got the problem

Comment: Just had a look and it was scripts from twitter which was causing the issue. when they were disabled everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had a look and it was scripts from twitter which was causing the issue. when they were disabled everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. If you have the Compatibility View button checked then uncheck it.

[IE Compatibility View](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/08/27/introducing-compatibility-view.aspx)

Comment: You could try to remove your commented out doctypes. Then I'd remove the external js files one by one and see if it starts to work.

Comment: Ok I have removed the commented out doctypes.

Comment: but it is strange that it works fine when I change browser mode to IE7 or IE8

Answer (score 0):

place this in your head section at first. Add the DOCTYPE to your html [more on DOCTYPE](https://hsivonen.fi/doctype/)

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">
```